# Grep variable for string in bash

Tags: bash, grep

**We'd like to search for `clid=*` (* stands for an number) in the following $test variable:**

```
Welcome to the TeamSpeak 3 ServerQuery interface, type "help" for a list of commands and "help <command>" for information on a specific command.

error id=0 msg=ok

error id=0 msg=ok

cluid=something2384fjdfkj clid=1 name=me

error id=0 msg=ok
```

**Final result should be `clid=1`.**

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `egrep` command:

```
egrep -o '\bclid=[0-9]+\b' testfile
```

`-o` option, tells to print only matched substrings

`\b` - word boundary

Answer (score 1):

This will print clid followed by one or more number:

```
grep -oP 'clid=\d+' inputfile
```

Or if it the input is from variable then :

```
echo  $test  |grep -oP 'clid=\d+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash has so called *here strings* which allow you to feed the variable's content to grep without an `echo`or pipe:

```
grep -Eo 'clid=[0-9]+' <<< "$test"
```